# How can we disable Dynamodb on AWS console?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Does anybody knows how to disable Aws Dynamodb on console? I have 100 of tables & my project is shut for 4 months but it will start again after this. So I don't want read/write capacity unit bill on each table. So I am finding any way to stop the Dynamodb instance or something which can deactivate my tables for this time of period.

Answer (score 3):

I think, there is no way to avoid billing when you have tables in DynamoDB.

What you can do is you can export the data from Dynamo DB now and import when needed. You can delete all the tables after you done export.

More info: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBPipeline.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use a new feature "pay on demand" then if you don't use your table, you pay nothing. But each request to your database will be costed *7. If you don't use your table frequently is a good choose.